# Detecting and deleting corrupted PDFs

Tags: pdf, corrupt

How can I detect, corrupt pdfs (using python)?

I have many pdfs. Some of these pdfs have become corrupted and should be deleted. How Can I detect and delete?

I used :

```
 from pyPdf import PdfFileReader

try :
     mypdf = PdfFileReader(file( 'sample.pdf', 'rb'))
except:
     print ' is invalid pdf'
```

But how automatically read pdfs from file and delete corrupted pdfs ?

Comment: Could you please clarify the meaning of a "corrupted PDF" term, should it be unreadable by Adobe Reader?

Comment: Seems you already know how to detect it. All you need is iterate files and delete file. Right?

Comment: Yes, How can I read names of all pdf file and delete damage of it?

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Reader actually includes a lot of auto-repair capabilities so it will open an awful lot of corrupt PDF files.

Comment: Yes, of course, but pdf files downloaded incomplete and not repair.

Comment: Then just check it has %%EOF in last 1024 bytes